# Unable to create custom entities in google dialog flow using node js

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Getting error below

(node:14284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: The entity to be added must be provided.
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (E:\workspace\dailogFlowApi\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:26)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (E:\workspace\dailogFlowApi\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:179:52)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (E:\workspace\dailogFlowApi\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:336:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (E:\workspace\dailogFlowApi\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:299:181)
at E:\workspace\dailogFlowApi\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:145:78
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
(node:14284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14284) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

````
exports.createEntityTypeService = (entity) => {


  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let projectPath = entityClient.agentPath(projectId);
      let entityPath = entityClient.entityTypePath(projectId, entity);
      let entityValues = ["testEntity1","test", "testEntity2"];
      const entities = [];
      entityValues.forEach((entityValue) => {
        
        entities.push({
          value: entityValue,
          synonyms: [entityValue],
        });
      });

      let entityReuest = {
        parent: projectPath,
        languageCode:'en-US',
        enitityType: {
          name: entityPath,
          entityOverrideMode:"@",
          entities: entities,
        },
        
      };
      let response = await entityClient.createEntityType(entityReuest);
      console.log(response);
      resolve(response);
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
};```
````

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You are using [createEntityType()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/v2.EntityTypesClient.html#createEntityType) and you are passing an incorrect value for the `entityType`. Thus the error you encounter INVALID_ARGUMENT.

[image]

As per documentation, parameters for [entityType](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.EntityType.html) are the following:

> - **autoExpansionMode** - EntityType autoExpansionMode.
> - **displayName** - EntityType displayName.
> - **enableFuzzyExtraction** - EntityType enableFuzzyExtraction.
> - **entities** - EntityType entities.
> - **kind** - EntityType kind.
> - **name** - EntityType name.

In your code `entityType` should look something like this. Just make sure to provide the correct values for each parameter.

```
enitityType: {
  name: entityPath,
  entities: entities,
  autoExpansionMode: autoExpansionMode,
  displayName: displayName
  enableFuzzyExtraction: enableFuzzyExtraction
  kind: kind
}
```